# Can CQ5/Adobe Experience Manager be used headless?

Tags: aem, jcr

No experience with CQ/AEM but been thrown in the deep end.

I have an approach where we'd have a web front end (built using Ember.js/handlebars) making calls to a web service which would in turn join the data (e.g. how many movies you've watched) with the appropriate content (e.g. the web service knows to look up node X in the CMS; "Thanks for watching all those movies!") and return the copy, image and data in a single JSON document.

This works really well when I have a RESTful API to the CMS.

However I've now been asked to make Adobe Experience Manager/CQ5 the CMS, and need to know if the same thing exists.

I don't think it does; I know that CQ5 uses either JCR/CRX as its content repository but from what I can see these aren't exposed as a web service (only language level APIs available)

AEM 6.2 uses JCR OAK which *promises* a RESTful API.

So in short my question is: does JCR OAK provide a RESTful API to the content and if so can anyone provide any examples/pointers please?

Comment: definitely AEM can expose the CRX as JSON. you question is related to same question  as [expose-adobe-aem-bundles-as-restful-webservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877499/expose-adobe-aem-bundles-as-restful-webservices)

Comment: You should really be careful regarding the load on the system. The JSON requests should be cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AEM comes with [Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/), which allows you to access the contents of the JCR through HTTP requests.

The `DefaultGetServlet` can allow you to render content in JSON format by using the `json` extension.

For example:

`http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/men.infinity.json`

Returns the following JSON (shortened for readability):

```
{
    jcr:primaryType: "cq:Page",
    jcr:createdBy: "admin",
    jcr:created: "Mon Jan 09 2017 14:44:46 GMT+1100",
    jcr:content: {
        jcr:primaryType: "cq:PageContent",
        jcr:mixinTypes: [
            "cq:LiveSync"
        ],
    jcr:createdBy: "admin",
    jcr:title: "Men's"
}
```

As of AEM 6.1, there is also a more user-friendly API based on [Siren](https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren); however it is not fully complete yet.

`http://localhost:4502/api.json/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/men.html`

Returns the following JSON (shortened for readability):

```
{
    links: [
    {
        rel: [
            "self"
        ],
         href: "http://localhost:4502/api.json"
    },
    {
        rel: [
            "assets"
        ],
        href: "http://localhost:4502/api/assets.json"
    }
    ],
    class: [
        "core/services"
    ],
    properties: {
        name: "api"
    }
}
```

These are the OOTB features but you can always create your own [Sling Servlet](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) to expose content however you like.

Answer (score 1):

If, by headless, you mean whether you can use AEM without using it to host your site then yes it can be used as a Restful content repository as explained by others. AEM 6.1+ has more support for SPA so you might want to investigate that rather than going down the route of using it as a content repository only.